# Can I Show View on any Imageview in Android Studio [java]

Tags: java, android, view

I have this type of ArrayList

```
public static ArrayList<View> mViews;
```

Created New Arraylist like this

```
mViews = new ArrayList<>();
```

I add View in the Arraylist like this

```
 mViews.add(stickerView);
```

and the View is Stored like this

```
StickerView{ad64560 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-1080,2022}

StickerView{79c1ed5 V.ED..... ......I. 0,0-1080,2022}
```

can I show the mViews list on any imageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understood your question but I hope it would help:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < mViews.size; i++) {
            if (mViews.get(i) instanceof ImageView)
                list.add(mViews.get(i));
        }
```